# there is a strange behaviour double parse string input?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

i try to read some excel file and converting some string column to save in db. BUT i face to face some double parse error: double result = double.Parse( 1,15);
result: 1.149999999999.... i dont want to see this. i want double result = double.Parse( 1,15); result = 1.15

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NumberStyles styles;
            IFormatProvider provider;

            styles = NumberStyles.Float;
            provider = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("tr-TR");

            string test = "1,15";
            double result = double.Parse(test, styles, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("tr-TR"));
            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `decimal` data type for DB and Application if you need the high precision data types.

Answer (score 0):

You parse as a float, but convert to double -- float isn't accurate, hence why you're seeing the error.

Your code should be:

```
double result = double.Parse(...);
```

and not:

```
double result = float.Parse(...);
```

---

Edit:

Side note: When you convert something to a string, use `value.ToString("R")` if you want a round-trip to occur; that would represent the exact value as a string, not a truncated value.

Comment: double.Parse isn't accurate either. But maybe the error is small enough for him to notice.

Comment: I've noticed that `float` is actually noticeable, whereas `double` isn't. But yes, if he needs a decimal type, binary inherently won't work.

Answer (score 0):

looks like error in the code: double result = **float**.Parse();
double.parse() should work fine.

Comment: i change my que but result the same as before

Comment: are you sure? It returns 1.15 then