# Wrong parsing from string to double

Tags: c#, .net, string, double

```
double value = double.Parse("4655.927411110702", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Why this parsing is getting me result: 4655.927411110702**5**?
Somehow it adds to my number 5 at the end. How should I convert this string to double and have a correct result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [there is a strange behaviour double parse string input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569164/there-is-a-strange-behaviour-double-parse-string-input)

Comment: Well, this question is beeing asked once in a week...

Comment: I'm not so sure this is such a poor question. Floating point questions come in many shapes and sizes which makes researching difficult, and the effects can be quite bewildering at first. I tend to answer only the well-written ones, and this fits that.

Comment: @Bathsheba You´re right, the question isn´t that bad. But definitly a duplicate

Comment: @Bathsheba http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673698/double-to-byte-type-conversion-error/40673854#40673854 this was a question I answered just seven days ago, which was asked nicely.

Comment: Nice plug ;-) I've just upvoted it.

Comment: Well, after all I think Alex got his answer. Stackoverflow is there to help people out. Most questions maybe will seem trivial to people programming some time, but I think most of them are still worth beeing answer, maybe just by linking the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't. Not all numbers can be represented exactly in double precision floating point, and the *closest* such double to `4655.927411110702` is `4655.927411110702450969256460666656494140625`, and the default formatting you're using trims off the majority of the "joke" digits.

C# does have a decimal type. Can you not use that?

```
decimal value = decimal.Parse("4655.927411110702", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```